# PHP trim special character destroys other special character

Tags: php, string, character-encoding, special-characters

I'm using this function to clean strings for elastic search:

```
function cleanString($string){
    $string = mb_convert_encoding($string, "UTF-8");
    $string = str_ireplace(array('<', '>'), array(' <', '> '), $string);
    $string = strip_tags($string);
    $string = filter_var($string, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $string = str_ireplace(array("\t", "\n", "\r", "&nbsp;"," &shy;",":"), ' ', $string);
    $string = str_ireplace(array("&shy;","&laquo;","&raquo;","&pound;"), '', $string);
    return trim($string, ",;.:-_*+~#'\"´`!§$%&/()=?«»")
}
```

It does all sorts of stuff, but the problem I am facing has to do with the `trim` function at the very end. It is supposed to trim away whitespaces and special characters, and worked fine until recently, when I added two more special character to trim away from string: `«` and `»`. This caused problems with another special character:

When I pass the word `België` into the function, the `ë` gets corrupted and elastic throws an error.

- Why does trim corrupt a completely different character?
- How can I fix
  that, so that I parse out `«` and `»` and preserve `ë`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`trim` is not encoding aware and just looks at individual bytes. If you tell it to trim `'«»'`, and that's encoded in UTF-8, it will look for the bytes `C2 AB C2 BB` (where `C2` is redundant, so `AB BB C2` are the actual search terms). "ë" in UTF-8 is `C3 AB`, so half of it gets removed and the character is thereby broken.

You'll need to use an encoding aware functions to safely remove multibyte characters, e.g.:

```
preg_replace('/^[«»]+|[«»]+$/u', '', $str)
```